# Need to regain complete control of folder

Tags: windows-10

it seems that I have corrupted or otherwise messed up the permissions on a folder trying to extract files out of it.
I have tried many solutions, none of which has worked yet.

I need to completely delete the directory so I can reinstall the program installed there. I have managed to be able to view the contents of the folder as my main user "Jaden" but cannot delete them due to the system being unable to access those files.

using `icacls` so far has proved futile.

`icacls "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Lovika_1.1.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C`

Returns with `Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 230 files`

and the files it cannot process are just labeled `: Access is denied.`

Comment: You cannot set permissions on this particular folder because it is a windows app inside the UWP, so it is logical that this won't work. If you get access to the folder, you will break UWP entirely, and then all your apps won't work anymore. But what you want to do instead is use settings -> App, and either delete storage/cache from there or uninstall from there, then install from the windows store again. Treat UWP as if it was on android. The same mechanism is in place.

Comment: Also, if you break UWP enough, the only way to fix it will be a completely fresh install of windows. Even windows upgrades will not fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't usually advise this, but if you still need to delete that folder...
You can run CMD.EXE as "TrustedInstaller" and make whatever modifications you need.

See below to webpages that contain programs that can assist you in this.
Obligatory "Use at your own risk."

**Process Hacker** (about halfway down the page) [Link](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-program-as-trustedinstaller-locked-registry-keys-files/#:%7E:text=Process%20Hacker)

**ExexTI** (from WinAero) [Link](https://winaero.com/execti-run-programs-trustedinstaller/)